# How do I create blank submodels when they are null

Tags: c#, entity, models

I have a model with sub models. Is there an easy way to create a blank sub model for all sub models that are null? Right now I do something like the following, but Room could have sub models as well. Instead of having to check all the sub models for null, is there an easy way to take house and automatically populate all the sub models with blank that are null?

```
House house = _houseRepository.Entity.ByHouseId(houseId).First();

house = house == null ? new House { } : house;

house.Room = house.Room == null ? new Room { } : house.Room;
```

Comment: I want to do something like house = house ?? new House {} and have it populate all the null sub models, but it doesn't

Comment: Please leave me a feedback on **solution 1**

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** You can use reflection to create instances for null properties. I created a method that will create an instance for *first level* of null properties like below.

```
public TModel FillNullWithBlankInstances<TModel>(TModel model) where TModel : class
{
    var type = model.GetType();
    var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(model, null);
        if (value == null) // null property than create instance
        {
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance( prop.PropertyType, false);
            prop.SetValue(model, instance);
        }
    }
    return model;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
 House house = _houseRepository.Entity.ByHouseId(houseId).First();
 house = FillNullWithBlankInstances(house);
```

---

**Solution 2:** You can use `??` this will check for null, and if is null will use what is after this like below. You can look on [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) for more examples.

```
House house = _houseRepository.Entity.ByHouseId(houseId).First();
house = house ?? new House { };
house.Room = house.Room ?? new Room { };
```

I recommend you to make a function that will do this for you every time when you need it.

```
public House FillNullWithBlankInstances(House house)
{
   house = house ?? new House { };
   house.Room = house.Room ?? new Room { };
   return house;
}
```

And the usage will be:

```
House house = _houseRepository.Entity.ByHouseId(houseId).First();
house = FillNullWithBlankInstances(house);
```

Comment: So if I have house.Agent and house.Room I can use house ?? new House{} and it will make a blank model for Agent and Room?

Comment: I understand your question now. This will make only for the `house` an instance.